# Convert xml duration ex P0DT1H0M0S into java

Tags: java, android, xml, duration

Hi i'm trying to read xml duration to a new duration but i't says 
"Cannot instantiate the type Duration"

I'm quite new to java and android dev. so please keep any nonconstructive comments to yourself..

the code

```
import javax.xml.datatype.Duration;

Duration duration = new Duration();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it myself.

```
        try {
            DatatypeFactory  dtFactory = DatatypeFactory.newInstance(); 
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Duration duration = dtFactory.newDuration("p0dt1h0m0s");
```

Edit..

The above is not possible due to a DatatypeFactory bug sooo i built this class to fix it myself..

```
public class XmlDuration {
    private String _xmlDuration;
    private int _years;
    private int _months;
    private int _days;
    private int _hours;
    private int _minutes;
    private int _seconds;

    private boolean _isNegative;

    public XmlDuration(String xmlDuration) {
        try {

            _xmlDuration = xmlDuration;

            _isNegative = ((String)_xmlDuration.subSequence(0,1)).matches("[-]");

            String period;
            String time;

            int tIndex =_xmlDuration.indexOf("T");

            period = xmlDuration.substring(0, tIndex);
            time = _xmlDuration.substring(tIndex);

            String numericSection = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < period.length(); i++) {
                char[] c = new char[] {period.charAt(i)};
                String s = new String(c);                   

                if(s.matches("\\d"))
                {
                    numericSection += s;
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Yy]"))
                {
                    _years = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Mm]"))
                {
                    _months = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Dd]"))
                {
                    _days = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }   

            }

            for (int i = 0; i < time.length(); i++) {
                char[] c = new char[] {time.charAt(i)};
                String s = new String(c);

                if(s.matches("\\d"))
                {
                    numericSection += s;
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Hh]"))
                {
                    _hours = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Mm]"))
                {
                    _minutes = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }
                else if (s.matches("[Ss]"))
                {
                    _seconds = Integer.parseInt(numericSection);
                    numericSection = "";
                }       

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }



    }

    public String getXmlString()
    {
        return _xmlDuration;
    }

    public int getYears()
    {
        return _years;
    }

    public int getMonth()
    {
        return _months;
    }

    public int getDays()
    {
        return _days;
    }

    public int getHours()
    {
        return _hours;
    }

    public int getMinutes()
    {
        return _minutes;
    }

    public int getSeconds()
    {
        return _seconds;
    }

    public boolean getIsNegative()
    {
        return _isNegative;
    }

}
```

Comment: I know this is old ... but this is great. But for many cases one needs to make comparisons or at least have a consistent unit. So I thought a simple enhancement would be the creation of a method that sums the results to a total number of seconds. But to do that one needs to know what the unit month represents. Is it 30 days? I assume a year is 365 days.

Comment: A bit late.. Thank you but this is just a simple conversion of the standard XML duration. Its better to use TimeSpan or something where the functions you are thinking of already exits.